# Create new content node upon user creation with populated fields from user profile fields d7

Tags: entities, tokens

why is it that ordinary tokens appear in fields where use is made of the "token field" and "field default token" modules?

I created a rule which creates a node with the username in the user creation form. I need to have fields in this new node to be populated by custom fields in the user creation form using tokens.

ordinary tokens work fine, tokens from custom fields either turn out as blank for the "field default token" module or as the token name in "token field" module.

Am I missing something?

More Information as requested in the comments:

I have custom fields on the standard user profile. When a user account is created, a content node is created, using the "rules" module. That node's name is pulled off the user profile using the "token" module, the token being for one of the custom fields. This works 100%. Now I want to do the same for two fields in the new content node, i.e. pulling content from the user profile's custom node's and placing them into the content node. This can be done with "field default token" or "token field". For some reason only standard drupal tokens work, tokens for custom fields don't, as described.

Comment: Oh, the terms of reference of the project are to only use stock modules. No code snippets or custom code should be used in this case.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which tokens return blank in which situations?

Comment: I have custom fields on the standard user profile. When a user account is created, a content node is created, using the "rules" module. That node's name is pulled off the user profile using the "token" module, the token being for one of the custom fields. This works 100%. Now I want to do the same for two fields in the new content node, i.e. pulling content from the user profile's custom node's and placing them into the content node. This can be done with "field default token" or "token field". For some reason only standard drupal tokens work, tokens for custom fields don't, as described.

Comment: Please update your answer with these new details so all of the information is in one place.

Comment: You mean my question?

Comment: yes question :)

Comment: okay,  got it done. Next time I will do that from the start. Thanx for the the help ... let's hope we get some replies that get me somewhere.

Comment: yesterday I found an article which hinted that one can not "autopopulate" fields of nodes which have not been saved yet. I tested with the default tokens and proved that this is not the issue. Just a headsup.

Comment: Which event are you using for your rules setup?

Comment: I fiddled so much with this now, I can't remember exactly which was which when I posted this a week ago. I dont think it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have to do with porting data from a content node field to a user node field. I solved this by creating the User and then creating the node with data pulled from the user node fields.